# How to find length of all .csv files in directory?

Tags: vba, file, csv

I have multiple .csv files that I need to find the length of in my directory. (The number of rows that have data in them.) I'm running the following code from a .xlsx file in the same directory. (I intend to copy data from the .csv files to the .xlsx file eventually.)

```
i = 1
FilePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
file = Dir(FilePath & "*.csv")
Do While Len(file) > 0
    Open FilePath & file For Input As #1
        length(i) = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
        i = i + 1
    Close #1
    file = Dir
Loop
```

All the values of the length array end up being 1, even though the .csv files are probably 15-20 rows long.

Comment: i think the problem is that you need to reference the opened workbook for the length. Try _ length(i) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row _

Comment: @pony2deer That still returns 1 as the number of rows

Comment: @pony2deer Note that I'm doing this from a separate .xlsx file that is in the same directory as the .csv files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually opening the file in Excel so you can't count how many *cells* there are. Try reading how many lines instead:

```
Open FilePath & file For Input As #1
    While Not EOF(1): Line Input #1, trashLine: Wend
    i = i + 1
Close #1
```

Alternatively, open the file in Excel - test - then close afterwards:

```
Set tempWB = Workbooks.Open(FilePath & file)
    i = i + tempWB.Sheets(1).Cells(tempWB.Sheets(1).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
tempWB.Close False
```

---

Or an even quicker way is to use Windows Script:

```
 Dim i As Long

 For Each varFile In _
    Filter(Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("cmd /c find /v /c """" """ _
    & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\*.csv""").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf), ":")

    i = i + CLng(Split(varFile, ":")(2))

 Next

 Debug.Print i
```

That way, if you've got 10 files the code is only working with 10 strings rather than opening/closing a file or reading thousands of lines...

Comment: Right, add to that that the `Cells()` call is going off of the `ActiveSheet` not the `#1` file having been opened in VBA.

Comment: Which way would be the fastest? The final result will have 1000+ row .csv files.

Comment: @codedude for a couple of thousand rows, maybe the first method (depends on your processor) for a particularly large file, definitely the second.

Comment: Also, `file = Dir` will loop through all the files in that directory so if you have other (non .csv) files they will also be read.  Filesystemobjects are pretty useful for looping through directories of files, instead.  Thesecond part of this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/29766396/4437159 shows the principle, you'd just need to drop in @SOofWXLS's solution above

Comment: added alternative method using cmd/WScript object

Comment: I ended up using the cmd method. It's much faster when it comes to longer files. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As `@SOofWXLS` stated, your code is not opening the files in Excel, you are opening them for direct i/o.

Here is a complete code sample that will fill your array with the file lengths as you were trying to do.

```
Dim fPath As String
Dim fName As String
Dim hFile As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim NumLines As Long
Dim length() As Long
Dim strLine As String

ReDim length(1 To 1)
fPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
fName = Dir(fPath & "*.csv")
Do While Len(fName) > 0
    i = i + 1
    NumLines = 0
    ReDim Preserve length(1 To i)
    hFile = FreeFile
    Open fPath & fName For Input As hFile
    Do While Not EOF(hFile)
        Line Input #hFile, strLine
        NumLines = NumLines + 1
    Loop
    Close hFile
    length(i) = NumLines
    fName = Dir
Loop
```

This will also dynamically expand your array to accommodate as many files as are found.